# Is it always safe to define sonar.forceAnalysis=true for SonarQube analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

When parallel SonarQube analyses are started, all but one will be rejected / fail with error: `The project is already being analysed.`

I learned on this [mailing list entry](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/SonarException-The-project-is-already-been-analysing-td5012233.html) that it is possible to override this check by adding `--define sonar.forceAnalysis=true` to my Apache Maven command.

Thus (to repeat the title): Is it **always** safe to define `sonar.forceAnalysis=true` for SonarQube analysis?

Why do I care / ask?

1. I would like to know about any interesting corner cases or concerns about using this flag.  Examples: Are there downsides or risks?  Could I corrupt my SonarQube database?
2. I have a TeamCity cloud with multiple build agents.  If more than one agent triggers a build (after multiple, successive version control commits), some SonarQube analyses may overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property is deprecated since SonarQube 3.5 and no longer necessary. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Failedtoanalyseaprojectasanotheranalysisonthesameprojectseemstoberunningatthesametime(SonarQube3.4only)